# Is it possible to move the files in folder to different subfolders according to database school_id

Tags: codeigniter

I have done an image upload function for large registration functionality. My uploaded files are stored in a single folder.. but I want to move those files into a separate folder with id stored in the database. is it possible to move those files into separate folders now??

I want to move the uploaded files into a folder with the name of id in the database. I cant do it manually since the uploads folder has many thousands of images. is it possible to do it in code?

```
public function add_applicants()
{
    if (isset($_FILES['photo']) == 1) {
        $config['upload_path'] = FCPATH . 'uploads/';
        $this->upload_path = $config['upload_path'];

        if ($this->validate_upload_path() == TRUE)
        {
            $config['upload_path'] = $this->upload_path;
        }
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg';
        $config['max_size'] = 2000;
        $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
        $config['overwrite'] = true;
        $config['file_name'] = date('Ymdhis') . '.jpg';
        $file_name = $config['file_name'];
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('photo')) {
            $this->upload->display_errors();
        }
    }

    $data = $this->input->post();
    $data['photo'] = $file_name;

    $insetapplicants = $this->Welcome_Model->insertApplicants($data);
    if ($insetapplicants == 'Success') {
        echo "<script>

        alert('New Applicants Added Successfully');
        window.location.href='dashboard';
        </script>";
    }
}

public function index() {
    $data['mediumwise_details'] = $this->Welcome_Model->mediumwise_home();
    $this->load->view('home',$data);
}
```

I expect that the files are moved to different folders 
For example, my uploads folder has 10 photos of different school_Id stored in the same folder. but I want if 2 photos are from one school_id means, a folder name with that school_id is created and that 2 photos are placed inside that folder. likewise different folder for different school_id 's

Comment: Do you want to move already uploaded files? please mention the database structure so we can help you.do you store your file name to the database?

Comment: yes i do store the filename in the database

Comment: CREATE TABLE `mts_applicants` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name_of_exam` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `name_candiadte` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `school_code` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `income_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `photo` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9782 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the following code will help you. let me know if it does not work.
create on function or method in controller place following code and run that function make necessary changes I have created below code based on the information you have given us.

```
$result = $this->db->get('mts_applicants')->result_array();
if($result){
    foreach($result as $row){
        $old_path = FCPATH . 'uploads/';
        $new_path = FCPATH . 'uploads/'.$row['school_code'].'/';
        $old_name = $old_path.$row['photo'];
        $new_name = $new_path.$row['photo'];
        if(!is_dir($new_path)){
            mkdir($new_path, 0777, true);
        }
        rename($new_name, $old_name) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: I used the above code, it is throwing this error                                       
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: rename(/opt/lampp/htdocs/hall_tick_home/uploads/335/20190913044901.jpg,/opt/lampp/htdocs/hall_tick_home/uploads/20190913044901.jpg): No such file or directory

Filename: controllers/Admin.php

Line Number: 85

Backtrace:

File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/hall_tick_home/application/controllers/Admin.php
Line: 85
Function: rename

File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/hall_tick_home/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: have you checked 20190913044901.jpg exist in hall_tick_home/uploads folder did hall_tick_home/uploads/335/ folder created??

Comment: yes i checked... that image is missing.. thank you so much friend  your code worked very well.. thanks for your help :)

Comment: pleasure to help

Comment: i have done image upload for a registration functionality.. the registrations are over... now the image names are in database.. but in uploads folder, some images are missing. Now what I want is to get the report of the rows whose images are missing in the folder.

i want the report of the rows whose images are missing in the folder

Comment: you can do as follows $result = $this->db->get('mts_applicants')->result_array();
if($result){
    foreach($result as $row){
        $old_path = FCPATH . 'uploads/';
        $file_name = $row['photo'];
        $old_name = $old_path.$file_name;
        if (file_exists($old_name)) {
            echo "The file $old_name exists";
        }else {
            echo "The file $old_name does not exists";
        }
    }
}